# replace an occurrence with a distinct number every loop

Tags: python-3.x, replace

The first occurrence of the character in the string will be replaced with a 1, the second occurrence with a 2, etc.

ive tried using for loop and the max function to replace the last occurence but it doesnt seem to work.

```
string=str(input('string: '))
x=input('character: ')
list=[]
for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i]==x:
        list.append(i)
        Z=str(max(list))
        print(string.replace(x,Z,[::-1]))
```

the output should be as following

string: departmentofcomputerscience

character: e

d1partm2ntofcomput3rsci4nc5

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it.

Use a counter for each character in the loop, and store values in the list, then merge the list. Use the *current value* if not equal to the character, *counter* otherwise:

```
string=str(input('string: '))
x=input('character: ')
# Use list to store results and a counter
l = [] 
counter = 0

for c in string:
    if c==x:
        counter += 1
        l.append(str(counter))
    else:
        l.append(c)
# Merge the resulting list into string
res = "".join(l)
# Output the result
print(res)
```

For the input string: `departmentofcomputerscience`

and the character: `e`

The output is
      `d1partm2ntofcomput3rsci4nc5`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve the goal using a `list` and the method `replace()`:

```
string = str(input('string: '))
x = input('character: ')

list = []

for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i] == x:
        list.append(i) # add all indexes to replace to the list

if len(list) > 0: 
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        j += 1
        string = string.replace(string[list[i]], str(j), 1) # replace the element once at time


print(string)
```

> For string: `departmentofcomputerscience`
>   character: `e`
>
> **Output:** d1partm2ntofcomput3rsci4nc5

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace(s, c):
    '''
    @parameter s: input string
    @parameter c: input character to be replaced

    @return s: where every occurence of c is
               replaced by it's nth occurence
    '''

    so = list(s)

    j = 1
    for i in range(len(so)):
        if so[i] == c:
            so[i] = str(j)
            j = j + 1

    return ''.join(so)
```